# Error - NameError: name 'values' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I m trying to define a function and getting an error. Not sure why ...
Here is the code :

```
def summary_stats(col_name, col_data):
    values = {'column name' : col_name,
    'mean' : np.mean(col_data),
    'median' : np.median(col_data),
    'variance' : np.var(col_data),
    'standard deviation' : np.std(col_data)}

for key, value in values.items():
    print(key, ':' , value)
```

Here is the error i am getting :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-142109a9084d> in <module>()
      6                     'standard deviation' : np.std(col_data)}
      7 
----> 8 for key, value in values.items():
      9     print(key, ':' , value)

NameError: name 'values' is not defined
```

Comment: Your loop is outside the function. Note the indentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out ... i m new to python ... and learning it hard way ... the code is working now .... thanks again!!

Comment: No problem. Always remember the importance of proper indentation in Python. Forgetting that will bite you.

Comment: yeah definitely !!